# Extract Text in Cell w/ Multiple Spaces

Tags: arrays, excel, string, text, trim

I would like to extract: `1 High Street` in column `B1` and `Sydney NSW` in column `C1`. So far I have extracted column `B1` correctly using `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99),3),(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*99+1,99))` but when I try to extract `C1` using `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99),3),(COLUMNS($A:B)-1)*99+1,99))` I get `Sydney NSW 2000` I need it to return only `Sydney NSW` and omit the `2000`. Thanks

[image]

Comment: what version of Excel do you have?

Comment: 2019 are you thinking of the `TEXTAFTER` `TEXTBEFORE` functions? Wish I could use those.

Comment: `=LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99),3),(COLUMNS($A:B)-1)*99+1,99)),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99),3),(COLUMNS($A:B)-1)*99+1,99))-4)`

Comment: @mjac since its an address, you should add few more samples. It may happen some have 5 spaces in between and some have 6/7/8.

Comment: @Scott Craner does that full formula go in `C1`? If so, I get a `#VALUE`. Stepping through it the error occurs in the `LEN("Sydney NSW 2000"-4))` part of the formula.

Comment: Sorry the ) is in the wrong place: `LEN("Sydney NSW 2000")-4)`